# ubuntu 18.04 messed up youtube-dl upgrade result in errors

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

I upgraded youtube using youtube-dl -u and a bunch of other ways that I forgot because I only Copy and Paste them on my terminal. and now when I try to install other things my terminal says

```
martin@martin:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  youtube-dl
The following packages will be upgraded:
  youtube-dl
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/931 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,271 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 205863 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../youtube-dl_2018.03.14-1ubuntu18.04.1_all.deb ...
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: dpkg: error: unknown option --validate-version

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/youtube-dl_2018.03.14-1ubuntu18.04.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: dpkg: error: unknown option --validate-version

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/youtube-dl_2018.03.14-1ubuntu18.04.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
martin@martin:~$ sudo apt list --upgradable -a
Listing... Done
youtube-dl/bionic-updates,bionic-updates 2018.03.14-1ubuntu18.04.1 all [upgradable from: 2018.03.14-1ubuntu18.04.1]
youtube-dl/now 2018.03.14-1ubuntu18.04.1 all [installed,upgradable to: 2018.03.14-1ubuntu18.04.1]
youtube-dl/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic 2018.03.14-1 all

martin@martin:~$ sudo apt-get install youtbe-dl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package youtbe-dl
martin@martin:~$
```

Comment: There is a typo in the last command: `youtbe-dl` -> `youtube-dl`... Also, please run the following (as root or with sudo) before doing any new installation `apt autoclean && apt autoremove && apt update && apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: @FedonKadifeli this is an off topic question i hope you will answer me.. I only have one user and this user is martin@martin i use it to install things and this user `root@martin` is same right? Why when using root@martin in scp when I use same password it is denied. Is there a  way to get root@martin password?

Comment: If your `martin` user has `sudo` privilege, do a `sudo -i` from the `martin` user... Then you can use the `passwd` command to change `root`s password...

Comment: great help @FedonKadifeli on password